# Get current active application name in Windows 10 using C#

Tags: c#

I tried get current active application name (or process name) but in some application like Microsoft Edge is result ApplicationFrameHost. Is there way to get application name such as in Task manager?

My actual code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);

            private string GetActiveProcess()
    {

        const int nChars = 256;
        uint processId;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
        {
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out processId);
            return Process.GetProcessById((int)processId).ProcessName;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Then please create an answer with the solution - you can even accept it yourself. Do not put "SOLVED" in the title - the accepted answer will show it is solved.

Comment: Victor, if you like you can copy the answer I have given (click edit, select all) and paste it as your own answer. I will then delete mine. You can self-accept your own answer then, and you may even get upvotes for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution looks functional for me in form application:

```
       //aktivneOknoProces
        string aktivneOknoProces = GetActiveProcess();
        private Process _realProcess;

        private string GetActiveProcess()
        {
            string app = "";
            var foregroundProcess = Process.GetProcessById(WinAPIFunctions.GetWindowProcessId(WinAPIFunctions.GetforegroundWindow()));
            if (foregroundProcess.ProcessName == "ApplicationFrameHost")
            {
                foregroundProcess = GetRealProcess(foregroundProcess);
            }
            if(foregroundProcess != null)
            {
                app = foregroundProcess.ProcessName;
            }
            return app;
        }

        private Process GetRealProcess(Process foregroundProcess)
        {
            WinAPIFunctions.EnumChildWindows(foregroundProcess.MainWindowHandle, ChildWindowCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
            return _realProcess;
        }

        private bool ChildWindowCallback(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam)
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessById(WinAPIFunctions.GetWindowProcessId(hwnd));
            if (process.ProcessName != "ApplicationFrameHost")
            {
                _realProcess = process;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public class WinAPIFunctions
        {
            //Used to get Handle for Foreground Window
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

            //Used to get ID of any Window
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
            public delegate bool WindowEnumProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, WindowEnumProc callback, IntPtr lParam);

            public static int GetWindowProcessId(IntPtr hwnd)
            {
                int pid;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
                return pid;
            }

            public static IntPtr GetforegroundWindow()
            {
                return GetForegroundWindow();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
```

[GetCurrentProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ProcessName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname(v=vs.110).aspx)

That should give you the name of the curent process