# How to run code in a specified app and nowhere else (C#) (Visual Studio 2019) (Windows)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have made a very basic spambot which I use to promote my shop in a multiplayer Minecraft server, however the way that I coded it has it so it will type the text I want every x ms, but it will only type to an area where the cursor has sellected, meaning if i want to use google or word or something like that in the mean time, the spambot would start to type on there instead of the intended app. I looked around the internet to see if someone had asked a similar question but I couldn't find much detail. So I want to ask if I can change my code up somehow using Visual Studio 2019 so that I can select a certain app/program that is already running, which the code only works on there. If you have any specific questions about the code I've written, please feel free to ask me! Im rather new to C# so I don't know much but I'm hoping to advance in it, and this would help me out a lot!

(Edit - Added code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SpambotTrial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public bool FirstText = true;
        public bool SecondText = false;
        public int Speed = 30000;
        public bool Trial = true;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (FirstText)
            {
                SendKeys.Send(richTextBox1.Text);
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                FirstText = false;
                SecondText = true;
            }
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (SecondText)
            {
                SendKeys.Send(richTextBox2.Text);

                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                SecondText = false;
                while ((SecondText == false) && (FirstText == false))
                {
                    FirstText = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Start();
            while (Trial)
            {
                Task.Delay(30000);
                timer1.Interval = Speed * 2;
                Trial = false;
            }
            

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer2.Stop();
            timer1.Interval = Speed;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code. It's simply impossible without some fragment to tell what to change.

Comment: I added the code, hope it helps!

Comment: [SendKeys.Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send): sends keystrokes to the *active application*. You need to check active application before sending keys. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46176798/1997232).